# Show that $\nabla ·(\bar\Psi\nabla\Psi - \Psi\nabla\bar\Psi) = \bar\Psi\nabla^2\Psi - \Psi\nabla^2\bar\Psi$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, differentiation

Show that

$$\nabla ·(\bar\Psi\nabla\Psi - \Psi\nabla\bar\Psi) = \bar\Psi\nabla^2\Psi - \Psi\nabla^2\bar\Psi$$

where $\Psi$ is a complex wave equation, $\nabla$ is the gradient and $\bar\Psi$ is the complex conjugate of $\Psi$.

I have developped the gradient in terms of $x, y, z$ for both $\Psi$ and $\bar\Psi$, but I don't know if that expression is correct or not.

For $x$:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \left(\frac{\bar\Psi\partial \Psi}{\partial x},\frac{\bar\Psi\partial \Psi}{\partial y}, \frac{\bar\Psi\partial \Psi}{\partial z}\right) - \left(\frac{\Psi\partial \bar\Psi}{\partial x},\frac{\Psi\partial \bar\Psi}{\partial y}, \frac{\Psi\partial \bar\Psi}{\partial z}\right)\right) =$$
$$ =  \left(\frac{\partial\bar\Psi\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2},\frac{\partial\bar\Psi\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial y\partial x}, \frac{\partial\bar\Psi\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial z\partial x}\right) - \left(\frac{\partial\Psi\partial^2 \bar\Psi}{\partial x^2},\frac{\partial\Psi\partial^2 \bar\Psi}{\partial y\partial x}, \frac{\partial\Psi\partial^2 \bar\Psi}{\partial z\partial x}\right)$$

And then I dont know how to continue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's very easy. Can you write down what you have so we can see where you are confused?

Comment: Just hit the terms inside the parenthesis with the gradient and use Leibniz rule.

Comment: The first $\nabla$ is a divergence, not a gradient.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not bother with converting the expression into coordinates; you will make your life much more difficult. Simply use the pertinent product rule for divergences: $$\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot(\phi\mathbf{A})=\phi(\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{A})+\mathbf{A}\cdot(\mathbf{\nabla}\phi)$$
where $\phi$ is a scalar function, and $\mathbf{A}$ a vector function. The desired answer should follow quite easily, using the above.